# Get property's name by PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class like this:

```
public abstract class SomeClass<T> where T: new() {
    ...
    public void GetData() {
        ...
        var cur = new T();
        var properties = typeof (T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).ToList();
    ...
    }
}
```

where T can be something like

```
public class {
    ...
    public int SomeField {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

How can i get "SomeField" by properties?

If i call `properties[i].Name` i get "Int32".

There is `RuntimePropertyInfo` member in property, but i have no access to it.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't accessing `.PropertyType.Name` ?

Comment: I need to get "SomeField" but not "Int32".

Comment: which works fine (see example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine:

```
public class SomeType
{
    public int SomeField { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void GetData<T>()
    {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).ToList();
        var firstPropertyName = properties[0].Name;
        Console.WriteLine(firstPropertyName);
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        GetData<SomeType>();
    }
}
```

I think you're accessing `.PropertyType.Name` rather than `.Name`.

Comment: Seems like i'm totally stupid, sorry for this question.

Comment: @user3272018 sometimes we all just need fresh eyes; I've often struggled on things that - when looked at by someone else - were immediately obvious. Or, what also works well: take a break and come back to it ;p